# Glib error when trying to open Firefox and Thunderbird

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, glib, mozilla

I read the other similar problems but either there are no answers or the problem is not the same as mine.

Suddenly, without any reason, my Firefox and Thunderbird just stopped working. I click on the icon, it looks like it is starting and then nothing happens.

I am very fresh user of Linux and because I don't know the pro commands I just tried the following: I have opened the Terminal and just typed `Firefox`. What I get as a result is the following:

```
(process:11768): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion
'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:11768): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:11768): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:11768): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:11768): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised Could not
create gnome accelerators directory `/home/tonkata/.gnome2/accels':
Permission denied
```

Then, after reading some posts and without being sure what to expect I types in the Terminal locate glib.h. What I get back is this:

```
/home/tonkata/Ubuntu
One/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/config/blk/dev/bsglib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/config/blk/dev/bsglib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic/include/config/blk/dev/bsglib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic/include/config/blk/dev/bsglib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic/include/config/blk/dev/bsglib.h
```

So, what is `glib`? and why I have some `permissions denied`?

I am really new and just don't know what to do more. Please, give me your thoughts in a "for Dummies" style.

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be something significantly wrong with Firefox on Ubuntu.
I get perpetual crashing.

The troubleshooting suggestions I've gotten from various forums are absurdly bad.

Question:  Have you ever used a tor-based secure internet browser on your machine?

I'm going out on a limb here but I wanted to check for a correlation before saying anything.

Cheers

Comment: Hi! No, I've never used it. However, I know about it as being the most secure thing on the web. I want to check it sometime. Thanks for reminding me.
Is it connected somehow to the Onion? (or something..)